# What was the expected behavior of reset_password_token in Devise before version 3.5.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working on a legacy platform that has made use of older libraries and gems for quite some time, and we have a bit of time to update them.  One of these libraries is Devise, of which the original version was set in the Gemfile to `3.4.1`.

In updating this dependency to `~> 3.5.6`, I've come across a regression in one of the tests.  We set the `reset_password_token` manually in the test and assert that it appears in an email for future user consumption.

The test would look something like this:

```
describe ResetMailer  do
  context 'when resetting a user password' do
    let(:user) {
      User.create!
    }
    before(:each) do
      user.update(reset_password_token: 'the_expected_token', email:  'foo@example.com')
    end

    it 'includes a link with the reset token' do
      mail = ResetMailer.reset(user)
      expect(mail.body).to match('/#/reset/the_expected_token')
    end
  end
end
```

This ***passes*** with Devise ~3.4.1 and ***fails*** with Devise 3.5.6.  The test fails starting with Devise 3.5.1 (since 3.5.0 was yanked I can't test that one independently).

I believe that `reset_password_within` was introduced in this time, but in the interest of preserving backwards compatibility, what is the equivalent behavior in 3.5.x to 3.4.1 in regards to `reset_password_within`?  Is it an unbound time, or do I have to assume some period of time?

Comment: Could this be is a code smell that is telling you that your test is to closely coupled to the implementation? Maybe use a acceptance test instead where the "user" (in this case a large rodent)  clicks the reset link and verify the *behavior*.

Comment: @max:  I don't disagree that the test suffers from several flaws, as well as the acceptance criterion, but rewriting or engineering a new test is not an option due to other time constraints.  My question is focused on whether or not there is an equivalent behavior, and if there isn't, then I can discuss with project leads on what we would need to address the concern.

Comment: Easiest way to solve this would be to simply change the signature of your mailer method to match [the vanilla Devise mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb) `(record, token, opts={})`.  That way you can call `ResetMailer.reset(user, 'the_expected_token')`. This uncouples your mailer from the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, and it's the silliest thing.

In newer versions of the Recoverable module (first pioneered [in this commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/31901bc862db60878130fcd9cbf9c4895d41b2d2#diff-fa817bf486c518644016136465d914b2) and refined ultimately in [this commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/f71d843f9393fe0e718aadbfb3632c10ce353358#diff-fa817bf486c518644016136465d914b2)), a `before_update` hook was added to flush the token in the event of the email being updated or the encrypted password being updated.

```
included do
  before_update do
    if (respond_to?(:email_changed?) && email_changed?) || encrypted_password_changed?
      clear_reset_password_token
    end
  end
end
```

This means the way I was setting my test up was incorrect; **every time I updated the email I would be resetting the token.**

In the normal lifecycle of my application, this would never occur; I would not update the email address *and* update the token in one go, so the test itself is invalid.  In this context, adjusting the test is the correct solution.

What I'm taking away from all of this:

- Updating the email or password resets the token.
- If you do neither, you are free to set the token to whatever you like.